# Splitting comma-separated string selecting as columns with joins in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
name     orderid
bambino  4,5,6,7,8
```

How can we separate values in `orderid` column into different columns like in example below?

```
name     order1 order2 order3 order4 order5
bambino  4      5      6      7      8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tricks with `xml` and then pivoting:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      name VARCHAR(20) ,
      orderid VARCHAR(20)
    )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'chao', '1,2,3' ),
        ( 'bambino', '4,5,6,7,8' );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   name ,
                        Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS orderid ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY name ORDER BY ( SELECT
                                                              NULL
                                                              ) ) rn
               FROM     ( SELECT    name ,
                                    CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(orderid, ',',
                                                          '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS orderid
                          FROM      @t
                        ) AS A
                        CROSS APPLY orderid.nodes('/M') AS Split ( a )
             )
    SELECT  name ,
            [1] AS order1 ,
            [2] AS order2 ,
            [3] AS order3 ,
            [4] AS order4 ,
            [5] AS order5 ,
            [6] AS order6 ,
            [7] AS order7 ,
            [8] AS order8 ,
            [9] AS order9 ,
            [10] AS order10
    FROM    cte PIVOT( MAX(orderid) FOR rn IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6],
                                                [7], [8], [9], [10] ) ) p
```

Output:

```
name    order1  order2  order3  order4  order5  order6  order7  order8  order9  order10
bambino 4       5       6       7       8       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
chao    1       2       3       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: thnk you so much @Giorgi Nakeuri let me try

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed amount of values in your orderid column, this question could maybe help you:

[How to split a comma seperated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) is a really good webpage on how you can split an comma separated string into rows. There are many different approaches so pick a way that suits your needs. (Eg CLR will be faster than a XML 'hack', but this might not be a concern.)

Once you've got your data in rows you can then use `PIVOT` to turn it into columns. You might have to do this in dynamic SQL if you don't know how many columns you're going to have.

Answer (score 0):

Most simplest and dynamic query for this, This query won't mind if you have million orders in `orderid` column

```
declare @name as nvarchar(50), @orderid as nvarchar(50), @dorders as nvarchar(max)='',@count as int = 1
select @name=name, @orderid=orderid from abc -- add here where clause to select particular row
select @dorders = @dorders + splitdata + ' as [Order'+convert(nvarchar(10),@count)+'],', @count = @count + 1 from fnsplitstring(@orderid,',')
set @dorders = SUBSTRING(@dorders,0,len(@dorders))
declare @Dsql as nvarchar(max) = 'select '''+@name+''' as name, '+@dorders
exec (@Dsql)
```

For your reference

[image]

**Ohh.. And add this function**, its helpful anyways ..

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

Comment: What happens when you tables has 2 or more rows?

Comment: **side note:** If you are going to use and recommend a sql based splitter, `DelimitedSplit8K`, created by Jeff Moden is the defacto. You can read more about it [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) and its performance comparison [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

Comment: OP here asked for single row named `bambino`, if he adds to the question, i will have to change the query

Comment: OP mentioned a table with sample data as `bambino`. Are you going to assume that the table will always have only a single row?

Comment: I'm assuming he is fetching one row at a time as a result set (as he shown)

And he can choose which row by adding where clause where i'm assigning variable values (i.e., `@name, @orderid`). I've added comment to support my argument

Comment: thanks for reply @PravinDeshmukh let me try and come back to u